# Which one is more correct and natural: "drive in a car" or "drive with a car"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Would you tell me which one is more correct and natural: *drive in a car* or *drive with a car*? For example:

> Because my car broke down, I had to drive home **in** a rental car.
>
> Because my car broke down, I had to drive home **with** a rental car.

I haven't been able to find an answer on the internet, but I seem to have hear both used. If both are perfectly natural, is there a nuance or difference between the two?

Comment: When you say you hear both used, is this from native speakers? How often do your friends break down and rent cars? There are so many ways you could research this.

Comment: @Astralbee: My sentence is just an example. My question focuses on the use of "in" or "with"? I'm not sure if the peopele use the prepositins were native speakers, which is why I asked this question. I'd appreciate it if you told me if both "with a car" and "in a car" is natural? For example: I go to work in my car, I go to work with my car.

Comment: For the title question (where the word "rental" is not present), native speakers would just say "drive a car." Also sometimes "car" is omitted: "My car broke down, so I had to drive a rental home".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> "Because my car broke down, I had to drive home in a rental car." is the more correct.

The second option could (although it's not likely) be taken to mean that you had to drive home with a rental car accompanying you.

In the example given, with "in", it's unlikely to cause confusion, but a native speaker would probably find it odd. You don't typically say "I drove to work **with** my car".

Comment: This is right, and jives with usage like "Bob showed up in a Toyota Yaris", where we would never use *with* unless we are talking about a model car being carried.

Comment: @Kaz Don't you remember that last Corvette club meetup where Bob showed up with a Toyota Yaris? 

Answer (score 25):

You drive **over** (run over) things **with** your car.

> I drove over a manhole cover *with* my car.  It made a clink-clank sound.

> I ran over the neighbors' pangolin *with* William's car.

You drive **to** places **in** your car.

> I drove to Cincinnati *in* my car.

You can switch these around.  People will still understand you but you may sound a bit odd.

Comment: Upvote for mentioning a pangolin, but downvoted for running over the pangolin, then upvoted again because pangolins are cool.

Answer (score 7):

They're both correct, and "in" is more common.

Also consider:

> Because my car broke down, I had to drive a rental car home.

You can also just say "a rental" rather than "a rental *car*". The car is understood from the context.

Comment: I don't find _go/drive with a car_ at all idiomatic.

Comment: @KateBuntig: Would you tell me what you find the most indiomatic?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope either "in" or neither ("driving a car") is idiomatic, I don't consider "driving with a car" idiomatic at all, either.

Comment: I agree with Kate and Esther.  Ngrams shows that "drive in a car" is much more common, and that's not even accounting for the fact that "drive with a car" could also match sentences like "I made the *drive with a car* that was barely working."

Comment: I *drive over* things *with* my car.  I drive *to* places *in* my car.  *I was driving to Atlanta **in** my car when I drove over a pothole **with** my car.*

Comment: It feels old-fashioned to me, but my mother -- also a native speaker -- would use "with".

Comment: @KateBunting I don't either, but "drive *somewhere* with *some particular* car" sounds fine to me (and my mom).

Comment: @KateBunting "correct" and "idiomatic" are not exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Acccumulation Technically you're right, but when I say something is "correct" to an English learner and leave it at that, I mean it's good, natural, idiomatic English, which is what I meant here. Others disagree, and I'm fine with that.

Comment: But 'I drove home with the shopping' is idiomatic; 'driving home with a rental car' emphasises that you now have something else in your possession that is going to be an extra faff to return.

Comment: @PeteKirkham "drove home with a rental car" can sound like you towed it along all the way home (similar to the shopping, which you carried *with* you)

Comment: "with a rental car" is certainly used and Google shows many hits, "with a car" is less idiomatic although you'll still find examples. Such is life. (Maybe it's because you're less closely linked to the rental car than your own car, or because people often ask questions such as "How can I cross the border with a rental car?" where you're not necessarily in the car but are wanting to move it.)

Comment: @Gotube I try to avoid using the term "correct" here on ELL. When a text has no errors of grammar or usage, I will describe it as "valid". When a usage is likely to be used by a fluent or native speaker, I describe it as "natural. I avoid the word "idiomatic" because it is so easily confused with the more specific term "idiom".

Answer (score 7):

Your first sentence, using "*in* a rental car" is correct. Your alternative, using "*with* a rental car" is grammatical but odd, as using *with* normally means that the rental car accompanied you, not that it was your means of transport. I might say, for example, that I drove to Port Augusta *with* my car if my car was on a trailer behind the vehicle that I was driving.

In Australian English the word "rental" is not used as a noun, so "rental car" could not be shortened.

Comment: just to add that British English is the same - and we'd generally refer to 'a rental' as 'a hire car'.

Comment: Nowadays I refer to them as ripoffs.

Answer (score 3):

From some viewpoint, U.S. English, there's no need to say "car" at all in these sentences, in the sense that it would sound odd to a U.S. native speaker. "I drove to NYC in a car" is just slightly less weird than "I drove to NYC with a car". In real life, people would say "I drove to NYC."

"My car broke down, so I had to drive home in a rental." sounds normal. Of course it's a rental *car*. Saying "rental car" would be a bit verbose, but still sound normal.

"with a rental (car)" would definitely sound abnormal here...

Comment: These days "I drove to NYC" may imply you drove in a car, though some might expect you to drive a truck. A hundred and fifty years ago it might be a horse and cart.

Comment: I still like Kenobi's answer to not use *any* preposition, at least in certain cases: "My Jag is in the shop so I have to drive a crappy rental all week."

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, *in* is correct here and *with* is not.

Even though, in many other contexts, you can use *with* to identify what you used to do something, that doesn’t work for vehicles.  Similarly, you ride *in* some types of vehicle (as if they were compartments that move) but *on* others (as if they were platforms that move).  It’s very arbitrary.

If I want to emphasize the mode of transport, I would use *by*, for example:

> Because my car broke down, I got home by bus.

> Because of my fear of flying, I crossed the ocean by boat.

“I had to drive by rental car” sounds odd, unlike those examples, but a little less odd than “with a rental car.”  I’m not sure why, but maybe it’s because *drive-by* has another meaning in American English.  (It will probably not surprise you that “drive-by shootings” are common here.)  A better alternative is to make the car the direct object of *drive*:

> Because my car broke down, I had to drive a rental car home.

This is how I would probably say it.  In this context, you could informally say, “I had to drive a rental home,” and let the other person infer that you were driving a rental [car to your] home, not driving a rented home on the street.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply, "I drove a rental car home?" No need for prepositions.

Comment: or I had to drive a rental car home.

Answer (score 0):

While I appreciate the above answers, there is a sense in the sentence, when using 'with' that I should report. Take a brief look at the definition of the instrumental case for nouns, ignoring for a moment that 'with' is a preposition. From Wikipedia:

In grammar, the instrumental case is a grammatical case used to indicate that a noun is the instrument or means by or with which the subject achieves or accomplishes an action.

Here the use of '*with*' in 'with a rental car' is describing how I resolved the problem of my car breaking down. The instrument used was with a 'rental car'.

In this conversation, how I resolved the problem is an important idea. I am saying, the rental car was instrumental to me in resolving this problem.
In reading the first sentence, the use of 'in', is simply a place preposition.

Answer (score 0):

Before cars, driving was a verb used for horses attached to a cart. The driver would sit in the cart and drive the horses (to make it move). The car is the modern equivalent. People say driving my car analogous to driving the horses and driving **in** my car analogous to driving (horses) while **in** the cart. Using with does not sound natural. However I might say "I had to come home **with** a rental car" to highlight being **without** my own car.

Comment: The verb 'drive' means: 'to operate a vehicle', you don't operate 'in' a vehicle. So, 'drive a car' will work.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rV1_7R_3cXA